# Worksheet functions of Excel in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How could I use MOD function and INT function in the VBA of Excel? Until now only some worksheet functions of Excel work in the VBA. I used the statement:

WorksheetFunction.namefunction

or

Application.WorksheetFunction.namefunction

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can just write answer = X Mod Y and answer = Int(X / Y) where X > Y in Mod and answer is the variable for the answer

Answer (score 1):

The WorksheetFunction object does not include all of the Excel worksheet functions.

However, there is a VBA `Int` function which works the same as the Excel `INT` function.  And, although the VBA `MOD` function is not the same, the Excel function can be mimic'd by either using the `Evaluate` method, or by doing the math.

```
Function modVBA(a, b)
   modVBA = a - Int(a / b)
End Function
```

Less efficient:

```
Function modVBA(a, b)
    modVBA = Evaluate("=mod(" & a & "," & b & ")")
End Function
```